What is the performance of a "meta" learner that performs internally CV for model selection?
I am trying to understand the proof that reporting CV performance during model selection as performance estimate is optimistically biased. The steps in the proof are the following:

Let $p_i, \pi_i$ the sample, true performance $\forall i$ (each $i$ corresponds to a configuration aka learner, e.g. SVM with $C=1$, SVM with $C=10$ etc)
$\mathbb{E}[p_i] = \pi_i, \forall i$ (unbiased estimation)
We return    as estimate $\max(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$
We return on average $\mathbb{E}[\max(p_1, \ldots, p_n)]$
True best performance $\max(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n) =
   \max(\mathbb{E}[p_1], \ldots,       \mathbb{E}[p_n])$ WHY?

\begin{align*}
    &\mathbb{E}[\max(p_1, \ldots, p_n)]
    \geq
    \max(\mathbb{E}[p_1], \ldots, \mathbb{E}[p_n])
    \\
    &\therefore \text{Overestimation}
\end{align*}
I can't understand why the true performance of the learner that performs internally CV must be $\max(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$.
To get the performance of this "meta" learner we need the following:

Split data set into train and test
Tune hyperparameters via CV in train
Estimate the performance of the best selected model in the test set
Repeat all steps from 1-3 for different datasets and average the performance from step 3 (this should be on expectation equal to the true performance of the "meta" learner)

Can someone prove why this performance must be equal to $\max(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$?

For example your average true performance $\pi_i$ is the true classification accuracy for each configuration $i$ trained on training data, then according to your linked reference and following your notation $p_i$ is the sample estimate of $\pi_i$ on the tuning validation sets and we expect that $\pi_i = E(p_i)$ for ideal unbiased estimations.
When selecting the model configuration with the maximum classification accuracy on the tuning sets, you are just selecting the configuration $i$ for which $p_i$ is maximum. However, the true best configuration would be the one that maximizes the true average performance $\max(\pi_1,…,\pi_n)$. Therefore $\max(p_1,…,p_n)$ tends to be an optimistically biased estimate of $\max(\pi_1,…,\pi_n)$ since when you select the configuration with the largest average observed performance on the tuning sets, you are likely picking a configuration where the estimate $p_i$ is not large just because the true $\pi_i$ is large, but also because of favorable random fluctuations in the tuning sets. In other words, the optimistic overestimation of the selected model's performance is due to the true performance of the (meta) learner being bounded above by $\max(π_1,…,π_n)$.
That's why the authors claim cross-validation when multiple configurations are tried is a form of optimistic selection bias and above intuitive result can be proved by Jensen's inequality via the convexity of the $\max(\cdot)$ or $\min(\cdot)$ function as mentioned in your reference as well.

Thanks for the answer! "Therefore $\max(p_1,…,p_n)$ tends to be an optimistically biased estimate of $\max(π_1,…,π_n)$". I understand this (follows directly from the Jensen's inequality). But is  $\max(π_1,…,π_n)$ the true performance of the learner? If not, how we are sure that we are overestimating the performance of the meta learner? To put it differently, $\max(p_1,…,p_n)$ is on average $\geq -10$ but $-10$ is not the true performance, why do we care about the optimism at all?

$\max(π_1,…,π_n)$ is not the overall true performance of the (meta) learner but rather the performance of the best possible configuration you could have selected. But you pick the model based on the best validation performance from $\max(p_1,…,p_n)$ , you may be selecting a model configuration that has overfit to the validation set. This model might not generalize well to new data which can lead to overconfidence in the model's ability to generalize such as poor performance on new data. Hope this clarifies.

Ok, now I get it. The performance of the meta learner is bounded by $\max(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$. And since we are reporting a performance that is on average greater than this bound, we are guarantee to overestimate the performance of the meta learner.

Exactly you completely understand now. Hope you can accept my answer or at least upvote since it's helpful for your understanding.

Is it possible to emphasize in your answer that the overestimation is due to the true performance of the meta learner be bounded (smaller or equal to) by $\max(\pi_1,…,\pi_n)$?

Added this in my answer as requested.
